# Getting property type CONDO from RETs

Tags: c#, rets, phrets

Trying to query the RETs database to only show CONDOs.  There is a lookup field in the METADATA-LOOKUP_TYPE of TYPEOFPROP, but I'm unable to pull the value. Query below:

```
http://connectmls-rets.mredllc.com/rets/server/search?SearchType=Property&Class=ResidentialProperty&QueryType=DMQL2&Format=COMPACT&StandardNames=0&Query=(LP=300000%2B)&Count=1&Limit=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using system names, filter on TPC.  You can then add "&select=tpc" to the querystring and add the filter ",(TPC=C)".

Answer (score 0):

Since its a look up, you need to use "|" symbol in the query.
Check this example,

> Perform a query:
>
> http://retsgw.flexmls.com/rets2_1/Search?SearchType=Property&Class=A&QueryType=DMQL2&Query=(LIST_15=|OV61GOJ13C0)&Count=0&Format=COMPACT-DECODED&StandardNames=0&RestrictedIndicator=****&Limit=50
>
> The response will contain the records you requested (limited to 50 due to the Limit argument given at the end). The COLUMNS line indicates the field names of the records returned and all DATA rows represent the records with field values in the same order as shown by the COLUMN row. If you’re only interested in receiving certain fields back, you can add a “&Select=” parameter to the end of the URL. For example, if you only want to retrieve back the KeyName field (noted as “LIST_1”) and the Listing Status field (noted as “LIST_15”), add “&Select=LIST_1,LIST_15” to the end of that URL. Note a few ‘LIST_1’ values for the next example.

For further reference, check this [flex](https://www.flexmls.com/developers/rets/tutorials/example-rets-session/) documentation